# Trying to get the count of documents a username can view

Tags: sql, function, select, count

So first I needed to create a table (UserPermissions):

```
CREATE TABLE UserPermissions
(
Document varchar2(15),
UserName varchar(15)
);
INSERT INTO UserPermissions
Values('Policy', 'SYSTEM');
INSERT INTO UserPermissions
Values('Menu', 'JDOW');
INSERT INTO UserPermissions
Values('W2', 'USAM');
INSERT INTO UserPermissions
Values('Permissions', 'SYSTEM');
 INSERT INTO UserPermissions
Values('W2', ‘JDOW');
INSERT INTO UserPermissions
Values('Form 1040', 'USAM');
INSERT INTO UserPermissions
Values('Policy', 'JDOW');
INSERT INTO UserPermissions
Values('W2', 'SYSTEM');
```

Then, Write a PL/SQL stored function that takes username as input and returns number of documents that user has permissions to view. If username is not in the table, your procedure should return, “User not found”.
So far this is what I have:

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION user_documents_func (UserName varchar2)
RETURN int AS
num_views INT;
BEGIN
SET num_views = (select count(*) from userpermissions);
IF num_views > 0 THEN
RETURN UserName || ' can view ' || num_views || ' document(s).';
ELSE 
Dbms_output.put_line('Username not found!');
END IF;
END;
/
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
```

I am getting an error on the SELECT statement "missing or invalid option".

I've changed

```
SET num_views = (select count(*) from userpermissions);
```

To:

```
SELECT num_views = count(*)  from userpermissions WHERE UserName;
```

and declared num_views this way

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION user_documents_func (UserName varchar2, num_views int)
```

Now I am getting the error "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: There is a difference between returning "Username not found" and printing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare variable first and then assign it.

```
DECLARE @num_views int; // thought as sql-server

BEGIN
SELECT @num_views = count(*)  from userpermissions WHERE UserName LIKE input_var ;

IF @num_views > 0 THEN
RETURN UserName || ' can view ' || num_views || ' document(s).';
ELSE 
Dbms_output.put_line('Username not found!');
END IF;
```

Comment: I've put in the declare and not getting: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
   exists prior external language